# git - merging one repo to master

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I have been working with someone on a web app via FTP but that of course had it's inevitable downfall so we are switching to using git. I switched over to git and have been committing on master, and he has been working still with FTP for about a week now.

We are now both getting on git, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to merge our files together. If I drag and drop his files from FTP on a new local branch, I `git add .`, `commit`, and `push` to the new branch. Then I `git checkout master` and try `git merge newBranch` and the files on master get overwritten with the newBranch's files.

I've read dozens of things on git but I can't seem to understand this in my scenario. Any tips on how I should approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the expectation on the merge? Do you want to merge based on the change date of the file? Or prefer your version/his version? I.e. how do you want to decide which version of each file to use?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand git correctly, but I want to 'merge' our files together. I know that there will be conflicts, but shouldn't they show up as conflicts after I merge the two repos together? I want to basically combine the two and if there is a difference in code git should tell me and I can go resolve it under my discretion

Comment: Did you start this new branch (for his files) based on a branch that already had your files?

Comment: yeah I think, I just did git checkout -b newBranch. And that put all of the code from the master (my code) into the newBranch. But then I dragged and dropped the FTP files into newBranch in windows (with the option: overwrite all)

Comment: In that case, that's the expected outcome. His changes are basically applied on your current version of the file. There aren't any conflicts, since you didn't make any changes at the same time. It would be different if you started at some point in time earlier, created the branch, then made changes in your branch and his branch, and then tried to merge.

Comment: You could get the desired result if you create the branch at the point where you started using Git. You can still do that. Create a new branch at the point where you started to use Git, then copy in his files there. If you try to merge that into your master branch, you should end up with lots of conflicts. Make sure you revert the previous merge from your earlier branch first.

Comment: Thanks. How do I create a branch from the initial commit or empty repo

Comment: Actually I think I can figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: `git checkout -b <branch-name> <commit>`, e.g. `git checkout -b myBranch 23478fd32` You can also use a tool like SourceTree to do this.

Comment: Repeat after me: "`git` is not a deployment tool. `git` is a distributed version control system. `git` is not a deployment tool. `git` is a distributed version control system`. ......."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

- Find the commit where you started to use Git, e.g. `123456`.
- Make sure you're on the master branch: `git checkout master`
- Create a branch based on the above commit: `git checkout -b ftp 123456`
- Apply the changes from the FTP server in this branch, commit them there.
- Switch to the master branch again: `git checkout master`
- Try to merge the `ftp` branch into master: `git merge ftp`.

You should end up with lots of conflicts now - resolve them manually, and then commit the changes.

To avoid destroying your master branch, you might want to do all of this in another branch, not `master`.